# Using a 'For' loop that outputs a list of positive integers starting from 1 whose squares are all less than 1000 and are prime

Tags: programming

The code I have thus far to my question is here:

```
primes[m_] :=
(Clear[list, primes];
list = {};
For[k = 1,
k^2 < 1000, 
k = k + 1, 
If[PrimeQ[k^2 < 1000], AppendTo[list, k]]];
list);
primes[30]
```

I changed my code but it is still wrong. I will get this after some trial and error, hopefully.

Comment: `Select[Range[Sqrt[1000]], PrimeQ]`

Comment: Look at the syntax for a `For` loop: `For[start, test, incr, body]`.  You need four inputs. You only have two specified.

Comment: I love the Select command but this is a specific task I must do using loops (Even though Select command is essentially running a loop in the background), thanks for the advice, I will mess around with it!

Comment: see [Loop alternatives](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica)

Comment: Okay, I can help you with that. But also, for fun: `Prime /@ Range@PrimePi[Sqrt[1000]]`.

Comment: Agreed with the above commenters, Also, you Clear the symbol 'primes' within the function 'primes'. So once you run it, it immediately clears itself, not the best idea in general. So yes, read the documentation for For and PrimeQ. Also. even if this code worked, it wouldn't return anything. I recommend returning the collected list at the end.

Comment: I like the answer below, but I am unfamiliar with a few of those commands so I don't exactly know what is going on..

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused on what I'm even trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct fix for your `For` loop here, I would say:

```
Module[{list = {}, k},
  For[k = 1, k < Sqrt[1000], k++, If[PrimeQ[k], AppendTo[list, k]]];
  list
 ]
```

Using `Sow` and `Reap` rather than appending to a list (which is slow):

```
Last@Last@Reap@Module[{list = {}, k},
  For[k = 1, k < Sqrt[1000], k++, If[PrimeQ[k], Sow[k]]];
  list
 ]
```

`Do` is better than `For`:

```
Last@Last@Reap@Module[{list = {}, k},
Do[If[PrimeQ[k], Sow[k]], {k, Sqrt[1000]}];
list
]
```

The loop-like construction I would use to do this problem:

```
Last@Last@Reap@Module[{n = 1}, 
  While[n < Sqrt[1000], If[PrimeQ[n++], Sow[n - 1]]]
 ]
```

Alternatively,

```
Select[Range[Sqrt[1000]], PrimeQ]
```

and, my favorite and probably the fastest,

```
Prime /@ Range@PrimePi[Sqrt[1000]]
```

Comment: Great! although I am very unfamiliar with module, sow and reap. I appreciate your method! I'm still trying to go about it in my original way. I have edited my original code above but still doesn't work.

Comment: [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) is a scoping construct. It basically does the thing you're trying to do with the `Clear` command by making *local* versions of the variables that don't leak out into the global variable space (i.e once the function is completed, `list` is left undefined). `Sow` and `Reap` are super-great. You should learn about them.

Comment: Clear[list];
list = {};
For[
  k = 1,
  k^2 < 1000, 
  k = k + 1, 
  If[PrimeQ[k], AppendTo[list, k]];];
list

Comment: @Brandon. Yep, that does it. (Also, see my previous comment: I forgot to ping you on it.)

Comment: I was able to figure out my original code, its right above this comment. Thanks again for sticking through this with me!

Answer (score 0):

Just another way:

```
Prime[Range@PrimePi[Ceiling@Sqrt[1000]]]
```